# Probably dataframe-based error when trying to create bar chart with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a simple bar chart from dataframe that I transformed from 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ZB3.gif) with this code:

```
df1 = data[data['PumpState'] == 1.0].groupby('Date').agg({'Pressure': np.mean})
```

to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkinK.gif). Now, this seems a little weird already (with the Pressure label above). When I try to transform it into the dictionary, it shows that 'Pressure' is key and Date is a value (with numbers exactly opposite).

When I try to make a bar chart from it, I get KeyError: 'Date' with this code:

```
plt.bar(range(df1.shape[0]), df1['Pressure'], align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(range(df1.shape[0]), df1['Date'].values[:], rotation='vertical')
plt.ylabel('Average Pressure')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.title('Average Pressure per Day')
plt.show()
```

When I swap

```
df1['Date'].values[:]
```

for

```
df1['Pressure'].values[:]
```

it shows the bar chart but the values on the x-axis are not dates but the pressure values. My guess is that the mistake is somewhere in that transformation where I use group by and age or maybe it is something completely different. Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a small reproducible sample data set (as text/CSV/Python code)  [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48476117/edit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is indeed `df1['Date'].values[:]`. The dataframe has no "Date" column. `"Date"` has become the dataframe index. Hence you should use the index instead,

```
df1.index.values
```

This would then look as:

```
plt.bar(range(df1.shape[0]), df1['Pressure'], align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(range(df1.shape[0]), df1.index.values, rotation='vertical')
plt.ylabel('Average Pressure')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.title('Average Pressure per Day')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Btw why has "Date" become the dataframe index? Can I prevent it? I need to do a certain loop through the data and I would prefer having the indexes 0, 1, 2... instead of having to reference individual dates. Thanks!

Comment: The `mean`operation creates a dataframe with the quantity that is grouped by as new index. That is just how it works and it definitely makes sense this way. If you want to have an index as a column, use `df.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
data[data['PumpState'] == 1.0].groupby('Date')['Pressure'].mean().plot.bar()
```

Comment: This shows _converter not defined error. If I leave out the `.plot.bar()` part, it gives me the same dataframe and the bar chart code still does not work.